# I am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting an array out of marks from this section, this section calculates the total mark by multiplying the weight of each assessment by the marks of each assessment. Any marks that gets a -1 is automatically set as 0 and not counted.

```
public double totalMark(){
    int [] assessments = {2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,3,70}; //Weight of each assessment
    int totalMark = 0;
    int overallmark = 0;
    for (int i : marks) //marks of each assignment
        if (marks[i] == -1) {
            assessments[i] = 0;
        }
    for (int i : marks) {
        totalMark =+ assessments[i] * marks[i];
    }
    for (int i : assessments) {
        overallmark =+ assessments[i];
    }
    return totalMark/overallmark;
}
```

This is my main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] samsMarks = {50, 60, 65, 60, 65, 70, 55, 66, 60, 73, 65, 45, 68, 54};
    int[] billysMarks = {50, 60, -1, 60, 65, 70, 55, 66, 60, 73, 65, 45, 68, 54};
    Student sam = new Student("1111111", samsMarks);
    Student billy = new Student("1111112", billysMarks);
    System.out.println(billy.totalMark);
}
```

Comment: What is `marks` here  `for (int i : marks)` it's not  declared anywhere.

Comment: @John it's likely an instance variable, or a static variable

Comment: @William read the stacktrace, it tells you exactly what's wrong, and on which line of your code the problem is

Comment: Where are you getting this error? What line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all your

```
for (int i : marks)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++)
```

and

```
for (int i : assessments)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < assessments.length; i++)
```

When you use

```
for (int i : marks)
```

`i` is not the index of `marks` but the elements that `marks` contains:

```
50, 60, 65, 60, 65, 70, 55, 66, 60, 73, 65, 45, 68, 54
```

Comment: you may want to go for 'length' instead of 'legth'

Comment: May or may not I should and I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the first answer you are using the for in this way:

```
for(element : list)
```

but since you need the index you should use it in the following form

```
for(initialization; termination; increment)
```

also a suggestion for the code instead of doing 3 loops through the element i suggest you do it in one iteration and you code can be as the following(since the number of element of both marks and assignment are the same)

```
for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
    if (marks[i] == -1) {
        assessments[i] = 0;
    }
    totalMark =+ assessments[i] * marks[i];
    overallMark =+ assessments[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are iterating `assessments` array with a `marks` iterator and they might not be the same length. Check that.

These 2 loops are very problematic (both are accessing `assessments` and worry only about `marks` length:

```
for (int i : marks) //First problematic loop
    if (marks[i] == -1) {
        assessments[i] = 0;
    }
for (int i : marks) { //Second problematic loop
    totalMark =+ assessments[i] * marks[i];
```

Comment: which would cause the exact same problem if the number of elements of the arrays are not the same

Comment: What would cause the same problem? I just copied problematic segment of the code

Comment: ok, what you posted is one of the problems, but not the initial one.
marks[i] .. the first value of i will be 50. do you believe there to be a marks[50] ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is more obvious mistake. This one is just the most common, so I just went for it. Thanks for pointing that out!